# __context__ attribute in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

In Kernel\include\linux\compiler.h

```c
#define __acquire(x)    __context__(x,1)
#define __release(x)    __context__(x,-1)
```

Please help me to understand, in above statements what we are trying to achieve with **context**. I couldn't find Its details.
I crossed It while understanding spinlock implementation in linux kernel.

Comment: [Sparse "context" checking](http://lwn.net/Articles/109066/)

Comment: thanks for the help , It helps me to conclude some for my platform.

Answer (score 1):

As from http://linux.die.net/man/1/sparse:

> -Wcontext Warn about potential errors in synchronization or other delimited contexts.  Sparse supports several means of designating
>   functions or statements that delimit contexts, such as
>   synchronization. Functions with the extended attribute
>   **attribute**((context(expression,in_context,out_context)) require the context expression (for instance, a lock) to have the value in_context
>   (a constant nonnegative integer) when called, and return with the
>   value out_context (a constant nonnegative integer). For APIs defined
>   via macros, use the statement form
>   **context**(expression,in_value,out_value) in the body of the macro.
>
> With -Wcontext Sparse will warn when it sees a function change the
>   context without indicating this with a context attribute, either by
>   decreasing a context below zero (such as by releasing a lock without
>   acquiring it), or returning with a changed context (such as by
>   acquiring a lock without releasing it). Sparse will also warn about
>   blocks of code which may potentially execute with different contexts.
>
> Sparse issues these warnings by default. To turn them off, use
>   -Wno-context.